# Pagination in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination

I want to create a GET path for pagination. I want to send records in parts. Is there any way to use Doctrine, sort the records and get the part I need?

Maybe I should use the query builder for this? Symfony gives any solutions to this?

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/getProductsInShop/{numberOfPagination}")
 * @param int $numberOfPagination
 * @param RecordsRepository $recordsRepository
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function index(int $numberOfPagination): JsonResponse
{

    //Is it possible to use a specific twelve?
    $records->findBy([], ['id' => 'ASC'], 12);

    $data = $serializer->serialize($records, JsonEncoder::FORMAT, ['groups' => 'records']);

    return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_OK, [], true);
}
```

Comment: You should use Doctrine Pagination to do that : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/tutorials/pagination.html

Comment: Why don't u use a bundle for pagination like KnpPaginatorBundle or PagerfantaBundle, u can check their documentation they are easy to use